# How to put value that has size of qword and bigger, in a dword array?

Tags: arrays, assembly, masm, 32-bit, dword

I'm trying to do a program that take 2 numbers , for example:
num1 = 123
num2 = 24
the program is doing a sum of the digits in num1, in this example, the sum is 6, and the program needs to print how many times do I need to add 90, that the sum of the digits will be equal to num2.
In this example, we need to add 90 twice because: 1239090--> 1+2+3+9+0+9+0 = 24

now, the way I'm adding 90 is by taking num1, multiply it by 100 and adding 90:
123*100 = 12300 --------> 12300+90 = 12390 (in the first time)

My problem is when the inputs are like:
num1 = 123
num2 = 42

Now, num1 suppost to be in the end= 123 90 90 90 90      **which is bigger then dword size!**

now I thought that I need an dword Array so if the result is bigger then dword size, it will put the rest of the result in the next dword cell of the array.
But I don't know how to do it , I have tried to put the result by pointing `EBX` to the `offset` of the array and then to put in `[EBX]` the value, but what's happen is that it just Compresses the value in the first dword cell of the array.

So how do I put the value that bigger then DWORD size in a dword array?
My code is:

```
.386 
.MODEL Flat, STDCALL 
option casemap:none 

SomeFunc proto :DWORD
MulBy100 proto :DWORD

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib

.data
    var dd 30 dup (0)     ;The array to put the result 
    count dd 0            ;count how many 90 to add
    SumHash dd 0          
    SumDigits dd 0
    fmt2 db '%d',0

.code

ReturnHashCode proc Number:DWORD
    mov SumHash,0
    Lop:
        mov eax,Number
        mov ebx,10
        xor edx,edx
        div ebx
        add SumHash,edx       ;num%10 add to SumHash (123-->3)
        mov Number,eax        ;num/10 go to Number   (123-->12)
        cmp Number,0          ;check if there is no more digits to add
        ja Lop

    ret
ReturnHashCode endp


MulBy100 proc thevar:DWORD
    mov ecx,99        ;adding 100 times the number to itself = number*100
    mov ebx,thevar    ;point to the var dword array
    mov eax,[ebx]     ;eax hold the num1 that we input (123 for example)
    MulLoop:
        add [ebx],eax ;adding the number to itself 100 times
        loop MulLoop
    ret
MulBy100 endp


start:
    INVOKE crt_scanf,offset fmt2,offset var        ;in this example = 123
    invoke crt_scanf,offset fmt2,offset SumDigits  ;in this example = 24
    countNop:
        invoke ReturnHashCode,var      ;return sum of digits to SumHash variable
        mov eax,SumDigits              ;in this example = 24          
        cmp eax,SumHash                
        je End_countNop
        push offset var                ;send the pointer to the var array dword size that suppost to hold the value (1239090....90)
        call MulBy100                  ;multiply by 100
        add var,90                     ;add 90
        inc count                      ;add to count 1 because we add 90
        jmp countNop
    End_countNop:
        invoke crt_printf,offset fmt2, count            ;printing how many times we added 90     
end start
```

Thanks to the helpers!

Comment: Appending 9 has the same effect on the digital sum as appending 90, and also you already know the effect: it adds 9 (so you could divide the difference by 9). Do you have to explicitly calculate the number?

Comment: @harold I didn't mention it, but I have to use 90, and not 9. this program is a part from a big program, and I have to use 90 in it. Can you explain me the second sentence that you wrote ("you already know the effect: it adds 9 (so you could divide the difference by 9)." ? I didn't understand what you meant.

 "Do you have to explicitly calculate the number? " - I also didn't understand this question.. can you explain what u meant?

thanks for the help.

Comment: Appending 9 (or 90) leaves the original digits intact, but you have an extra 9. So the digital sum goes up by exactly 9. Also, you can use `mul`, and you could store the thing in two adjacent dwords.

Comment: @harold but store in 2 dword still not helping me, because what if the numbers are make a result the bigger then 2dword? 

but you make me figure it out, I can take 123,24 and do: 1+2+3 = 6 ---> 24-6 = 18 ---> 18\9 = 2. and this is the number of time to add 90. but anyway, I want to know if there is a way to take a number that bigger then dword (like qword size) and store it in a dword array, without compress the number in a dword size.

Answer (score 1):

When numbers grow too big you need to cascade instructions. Here you can use the `adc` instruction. I'll show for 64-bit results:

```
MulBy100 proc thevar:DWORD
  mov  ecx, 99        ;adding 99 times the number to itself = number*100
  mov  ebx, thevar    ;point to the var dword array
  mov  eax, [ebx]     ;edx:eax hold the num1 that we input (123 for example)
  mov  edx, [ebx+4]
 MulLoop:
  add  [ebx], eax     ;adding the number to itself 99 times
  adc  [ebx+4], edx
  loop MulLoop
 ret
MulBy100 endp
```

Please take care to write the correct comments. You only add **99** times to multiply by 100.

By using extra registers you could easily transform this code to support 128-bit results.

Comment: You *do* realize x86 has a double-register sized multiplication instruction?

Comment: @EOF I most certainly do but with an array of 30 dwords that won't help us too much!

Comment: I'm pretty sure even schoolbook multi-digit multiplication will be easier and faster in that case.